# What is the significance of Agent Cooper's shoes being left behind?

Tags: twin-peaks

In the third episode of the third season of Twin Peaks, Agent Cooper is able to come back to our world. He does so via a power socket, and in the process leaves his shoes behind.

Once he's back, though, he's not quite himself: he appears as in a sort of trance, without his memories — like he's missing something.

Now, given this is David Lynch, I'm doubtful that Cooper's shoes being left behind and his nonresponsive state are not connected. Furthermore, [it's made exceedingly clear that "Dougie" doesn't have his shoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOVYcTQp3uI) when Jade's taking him to the car. Then in episode 5, "Dougie" keeps staring at a police officer's statue for a long time, while touching his shoes. And then there are [the recurrent red shoes worn by women in the show](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/07/twin-peaks-part-9-recap-red-shoes-agent-cooper-audrey-horne-wake-up), of particular interest being the ones from the woman that walks by in front of "Dougie" in the police station, distracting him from the flag he was staring at, and directing his attention to the power socket instead.

Finally, to add to all this, Cooper is only really back once he sticks a fork in a power socket — as if he'd finally gotten back whatever he was missing.

All this being said, I'm not sure about what the shoes might symbolize. Is it in some way a literal take on the expression "to walk in someone else's shoes," since Cooper is being confused by everyone as being Dougie?
Or do the shoes being left behind have some other meaning? Did Agent Cooper leave something else behind, that is symbolized by the shoes?